# Pass array values in the function in controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have been working over an application for over a month now. But I am stuck at a place. The scenario is not that difficult, but I think I am missing something basic.

Scenaro: I am collecting selected values of numerous dropdownlists in an array and passing them to the controller in app.js, that would save the value in the database.

Code for html:
Note: Alert is a custom directive that would generate dropdownlists on click of "Add Projects" button.

```
<div ng-controller="AlertDemoCtrl">
                            <alert ng-repeat="alert in alerts" type="alert.type" close="closeAlert($index)" ng-model="ProjectId[item.ProjectId]">
                        <ul style="list-style-type: none; margin-left: 0px;">
                            <li >
                                <!--data-ng-model="selectedProject[$index]"-->
                                <!--data-ng-model="test.ProjectId"-->
                                <!--<select data-ng-model="test.ProjectId" 
                                data-ng-options="test.ProjectId as test.ProjectName for test in items" id="Project">-->
                                <select>
                                    <option value="">-- Choose a Project --</option>
                                    <option ng-repeat="item in items" value="{{item.ProjectId}}">{{item.ProjectName}}</option>
                                </select>
                                <button type="button" ng-click="closeAlert($index)"><img src="delete.png" alt="Remove" style="height:20px; width:20px;" /></button>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </alert>
                            <button class='btn' type='button' ng-click="addAlert()">Add Projects</button>
                        </div>
```

Code for app.js

```
var CreateCtrlEmp = function ($scope, $location, SampleEmp, SampleProj, SampleDes, sharedValues) {
$scope.items = SampleProj.query({ q: $scope.query });
$scope.itemsd = SampleDes.query({ q: $scope.query });
$scope.save = function (item) {
    //$scope.item.ProjectId = new Array("5","8");
    //$scope.ProjectId = new Array();
    $scope.item.ProjectId = new Array(item);
    alert($scope.item.ProjectId);
    SampleEmp.save($scope.item);
    $location.path('/emp');

};};
```

I want to pass on the values in the save function. When I see the values in the firebug panel. I can see that the array contians null values in it.

If I pass static values in the controller then the values are saved in the database.

Please guide.

Thanx a lot in advance.

Tushar Sharma.

Comment: Not clear.can u put code on plunker/jsfiddle

Comment: I am trying on plunkr but its not working properly. Actually I have new dropdownlist generated when the user clicks on "Add Projects". Now say the user has had 5 dropdownlist. The selected values of all the dropdownlist is taken in an array. This array is to be sent to the controller and the values are saved in the database. Does this clear the scenario a bit?

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/IMTibPZz3RFNhJ69G00G?p=preview

Comment: plnkr not working can u give some examples of input and outout

Comment: We cannot get output as in, but the result would be, data being saved in the database. Now if you see the commented code, where I have declared the static values; The data is saved in the database.Hence This means that either there is problem in the ng-model="ProjectId[item.ProjectId]" (which may be sending null values), or I have declared ng-model in the wrong place, which may not be able to hold null values. Or it is problem in the app.js file, that I am not able to pass proper argument in the function.

Comment: Should I add some more description or is it unclear still? I think the ng-model isnt defined at the right place. What do u say?

Comment: Got one more clue. The ng-model is not binding the array to the selected values. Hence its declaration is at the wrong place, may be the array argument too.!

Comment: i need also alert directive description

Comment: the alert is nothing but just a custom directive i have defined. The purpose is to generate new dropdownlists when we click on add more. I have added that code in the script.js file in the plunkr.

Comment: There is a function "AlertDemoController" for it in the script.js file. Did this help you get things clear. Also when I removed the ng-model from the html file, no difference was seen in the working. This means that the compiler is taking the empty array from the controller file. That means we are not able to bind the selected values of the dropdown. A possible case may be that the ng-model is not able to hold the selected values. Whats your say on that?

Comment: {"FirstName":"asdf","LastName":"asdf","Email":"asdf@asdf.com","DesignationId":11,"ProjectId":[null]}

Comment: this is the json data that is posted to the server. I have extracted this from the firebug panel.

Comment: please add files on plunker

Comment: The files are added. There are only 2 required that contain all the code. index.html and script.js. What more files are you talking about? They should suffice I think.